# Samsung TV: new Date() returns the wrong date

Tags: reactjs, date, television

In a React app for Samsung TV i'm trying to get current date:

```
console.log('date', new Date());
```

Result:

```
Fri Jul 13 2018 19:49:01 GMT+0300 (EEST)
```

But current date is:

```
Fri Jul 16 2018 10:58:00 GMT+0300 (EEST)
```

If turn off and turn on power of the TV then `new date()` will return correct date.

How to get the current date without turning off the TV?

Comment: This sounds like a bug in Samsung's implementation.

Comment: Stupid question, but is your date on Tv is the correct date ?

Comment: the date on TV is correct